# Spring Boot - Access denied unable to connect to MySql DB

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, spring-config

I have a fresh Spring Boot application setup. I'm trying to connect to MySql using Liquibase with the configuration below.

```
#  Development DataSource #
   spring:
   datasource:
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cstmngtdatabase?
   autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
        username: root
        password: xxxx
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#  Liquibase Configuration #
   liquibase:
       enabled: true
       change-log: classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml
```

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.realcomplex</groupId>
    <artifactId>cstmngt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>business-logic</module>
        <module>web-ui</module>
        <module>web-service</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>cstmngt-project</name>
    <description>Real Complex&#39;s Construction Management Project.</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

But I got this error.
Error log

```
2018-02-15 17:39:44.407  INFO 27220 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
2018-02-15 17:39:44.488  INFO 27220 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@58f31629, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@64502326, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@42e4e589, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@39da5e49, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2180e789, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4a058df8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4ef4f627, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@124d26ba, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@63fd4dda, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@794f11cd, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@19b07407]
Thu Feb 15 17:39:45 ICT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-02-15 17:39:45.193 ERROR 27220 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:385) [liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) [spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.realcomplex.WebServiceSpringBootApplication.main(WebServiceSpringBootApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]

2018-02-15 17:39:45.195  WARN 27220 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-02-15 17:39:45.196  INFO 27220 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-02-15 17:39:45.198  INFO 27220 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-02-15 17:39:45.212  INFO 27220 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-15 17:39:45.217 ERROR 27220 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

I tried all of the solutions for similar problems here but none of them seem to work out. When I added @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) to class WebServiceSpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer it doesn't error, but it doesn't connect to database too. How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Junior Frogie, try to add mysql-connector dependency in your pom.xml (with scope runtime).

Comment: Hi @JúlioDias I have included mysql dependency in pom, I saw it in external libraries too, but still got error

Comment: 1) Are you sure you are accessing the same instance of MySQL? If not 
2) Are you sure your password is correctly set for root? (I doubt it'll be this)